# Create random records based on existing data with MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

On the basis of existing tables we need to create a randomized set. This is what we tried records are created but all fields are NULL;

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `create_data` ()
BEGIN
    declare done bool default false;
    declare anrede varchar(50);
    declare vorname varchar(50);
    declare nachname varchar(50);

    declare _vorname cursor for select anrede, vorname from vorname order by rand();
    declare _nachname cursor for select nachname from nachname order by rand();

    declare continue handler for not found set done = true;

    open _vorname;
    open _nachname;

    create_record: loop
        fetch _vorname into anrede, vorname;
        fetch _nachname into nachname;

        insert into lp values( null,
            anrede,
            vorname,
            nachname
        );
        if done then
            leave create_record;
        end if;

    end loop;
END
```

what did we miss here?

Comment: Got an error message for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE lp`

The whole procedure can be simplified to one statement:

```
INSERT into lp 
       ( anrede, vorname, nachname )
    SELECT null,
        v.anrede,
        v.vorname,
        v.nachname
      FROM vorname AS v
      JOIN nachname AS n  ON TRUE
      ORDER BY RAND();
```

That could be a big table (size of vorname times size of nachname).  If you want a smaller table (like what you were trying to do), then

```
INSERT into lp 
       ( anrede, vorname, nachname )
    SELECT
        ( SELECT anrede FROM vorname ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) AS anrede,
        ( SELECT vorname FROM vorname ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) AS vorname,
        ( SELECT nachname FROM nachname ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ) AS nachname
      LIMIT 1000;
```

This second version mixes up the name parts randomly and produces exactly 1000 names.

Using `INSERT...SELECT...;` avoids the need for declaring variables and looping.  And is probably much faster.

I assume the `NULL` was aimed for an `AUTO_INCREMENT`; leaving it out (as I did) has the same effect.